# How to convert a string to a number in php to sort in right order

Tags: php, string, sorting

With the below code I get the time left to arrival from an API with [DisplayTime]

```
.  $output .= "<ul><li><strong>" . $metro['DisplayTime'] . ".</strong>
```

Currently it gets ordered only by the first number, for example 
11 min. 
22:07.
26 min.
6 min.
8 min.

But I would need it to be sorted correctly by the full number value: 
Next train arrives in:
6 min.
8 min.
11 min.
26 min.
22:07. (24 hour clock time should be displayed after the time in minutes)

The full code snippet:

```
 <?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a['DisplayTime'] == $b['DisplayTime']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['DisplayTime'] < $b['DisplayTime']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$url = 'http://api.whateverurl.com';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);

usort($json['ResponseData']['Metros'], "cmp");

foreach ($json['ResponseData']['Metros'] as $metro) {
    if ($metro['DisplayTime'] != "Now") {
        $output .= "<ul><li><strong>" . $metro['DisplayTime'] . ".</strong>  
</li>";
    } else {
        $output .= "<ul style='display:none;'><li><strong>" . 
$metro['DisplayTime'] . " departs </strong></li>";
    }
    $output .= "<li>" . $metro['GroupOfLine'] . "</li>";
    $output .= "<li> nr " . $metro['LineNumber'] . "  </li>";

    $output .= "<li> to<strong> " . $metro['Destination'] . "</strong></li>
</ul>";
}

echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) then [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)?

Comment: Where is your comparison function? "cmp"?

Comment: What about hours... Can be in result 2 hours? `intval` make from `22:07` just `22` so this value will be put before 26 min. You should remove colon first.

Comment: Ooops, the cmp did not get displayed at first, made an edit, its displayed at the top of the code snippet now

Comment: I changed usort to natsort, which solved part of the sorting. But the clock time is still wrong. It displayes the order like 9 min, 17 min, 19 min, 22:57, 24 min, 26 min,. The time should be last.

Comment: What about some preprocessing? Walk through all items and normalize times (`intval(str_replace(":", "", $metro['DisplayTime]);`) and save it to `$metro['DisplayTime_normalized]`) and then use this normalized value for sorting?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this depending on your setup.  You could use ORDER by in your query. You could use php split on the first space to separate the the integer from the string.  $numMins= split(" ", $fullString, 2);  $numMins[0] would hold the number ( use intVal($numMins[0]) to make it a num). Push that value into an array, then just sort the final array.  Conact "mins." to the num if you want it displayed.